# Is Beckham's Pepsi beach commercial real?

Tags: advertising, video

There is this [commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68izU5g0CR0) which David Beckham did for Pepsi where he kicks three soccer balls into three different cans at a considerable distance on the beach.

The video went viral and we can see people debating on online forums if it is fake or real and arguing about Beckham's soccer skills. :-)

In these times where we can alter almost everything digitally, can we figure out whether this particular video is for real ? Any articles/blogs which can explain it.

Comment: An ["online video marketing guide"](http://www.reelseo.com/pepsi-shows-wrong-fake-viral-video/) explains that *"One of the most popular ways for brands to reach huge audiences with online video is to create a clip that begs the question, 'Was that real or fake?'"* in other words, these type of adverts are routinely faked.

Comment: However, for the same reason, they're nearly always plausible.  In this video you can see that they [sometimes have to do more than one take](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zR3Z2P4l0H0).  An outtakes video, behind the scenes or the original raw footage would settle this.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Ugh, another misuse (not by you) of "begs the question". http://begthequestion.info

Comment: RedGrittyBrick's link is to a piece which talks specifically about Beckham's Pepsi beach commercial, and which gives its reasons for believing that it's fake.

Comment: Is the question here *Can David Beckham hit three difficult shots in a row?* or *Was this a spontaneous, candid moment?*  The former is plausible and the video I added supports this.  The latter is obviously false based on the acting and the convenient two extra balls that just appeared when they were needed, not to mention three conveniently placed bins.